# How to display changing of graphite counter in time (in grafana)?

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have a question. I send counter to graphite. It increases every time somebody uses endpoint. So, it increases slowly during the day. I want to display on dashboard amount of connections during time (histogram - one bar graph per 5 minutes). For example, i now have smth like this[image: screenshot]
.
And I want grafana to display changes in time (5 min). It started in 13:31. so i want one bar graph(from 13:31 too 13:36) that will have value 12, next bar grapgh with value 0 and e.t.c (For example, if counter increases by 3, next bar graph will have value 3). I have no ideas, how to do it and will be glad if you help.

Answer (score 1):

For rate of change over time, Have a look at the perSecond function of Graphite.

For actual change (i.e the derivative) for your usecase id lookat the nonNegativeDerivative Function

https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html

I used this (as per the example) to calculate Network traffic

Comment: It displays in the very strange way. I am waiting for 12 value, but get 0.4 (what does it mean?) and how to make it 12?